# Creat not query in CakePhp

Tags: cakephp

How can I do this query in CakePhp?

select id from users where id not in (select userid from user_details ud join users u ON u.id=ud.userid AND ud.`name` ='fullname');

Answer (score 2):

to obtain your exact query you have to do:

```
$this->User->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'fields' => array('User.id'),
        'conditions' => array('id NOT IN (select userid from user_details ud join users u ON u.id=ud.userid AND ud.name ='fullname')' 
    );
```

but you can simply achieve the same result doing

```
$this->User->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'fields' => array('User.id'),
        'conditions' => array('UserDetail.name !=' => 'fullname'),
        'contain' => array('UserDetail')
    );
```

assuming your `User` model is in realtionship (hasOne?) with `UserDetail`

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way. but not a native cakephp, always try to do with find() method.

```
$this->User->Query("select id from users where id not in (select userid from user_details ud join users u ON u.id=ud.userid AND ud.name ='fullname')");
```